# How do I put StyledDocuments together in Java?

Tags: java, jtextpane, styleddocument

I want to make a StyledDocument from 2 other StyledDocuments in Java. Is there a possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it's not possible to sum two documents this way. Each document has own structure of Elements (nodes, Leaves). To merge them properly you in fact need to copy all branches with sub nodes from one document instance ot another.

The link shows how it could be done.
http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_documents.html